# Should a class be responsible for its own configuration

Tags: c#, configuration

In my workplace I am seeing an issue which I feel is wrong, but I am open to the idea that maybe the way I do it is wrong.

A minor example would be a class accepting configuration

```
//pull config from config file, then pass in to class
public class SomeClass()
{
   public SomeClass(string connectionString, string someOtherRequiredConfiguration)
   {
      //Do stuff
   }
}
```

In comparison, a class responsible for its own configuration

```
public class SomeClass()
{
    public SomeClass(){
       //Do work to pull from config file in constructor or in parameter
    }        
}
```

I think the second way makes DI much easier and also the class is responsible for retrieving the configuration it cares about.

Is there a prefered method?

Comment: _I think the second way makes DI much easier_ are you sure? How you can inject different implementation of "pulling" configuration if class will do it by itself

Comment: You could have an IConfigRepository or something if you wanted to control that separately.  If I was sure i wouldn't be asking. But pulling the config values and passing them in at the composition root feels wrong to me.

Comment: If you asking about should I inject an abstraction which "pull" required data or already "pulled" data, then I afraid there no clear answer with information you provided. If `SomeClass` can exist without configuration details, then passing `IConfigurationLoader` can be good enough idea. On other hand if `SomeClass` cannot be functional without configuration data, then, I think, having constructor with those details, will be more comprehensible approach. You can have some kind of builder for `SomeClass` then.

Comment: I strongly prefer passing a config to the constructor if the config is serialized (which it is if it is stored in a file). This goes well with the single responsibility prinicple: `SomeClass` already has one responsibility (otherwise you wouldnt need it), serializing it is another responsibility. Say you change the file format from xml to ini, then you only need to change `SomeClassConfig`. Depending on the serialization framework, you may not even have to change the config class. However, if `SomeClass` loads itself from some path, you have a hardcoded dependency to the file and its format.

Comment: @pschill, as James suggested you could have `IConfigRepository` and inject it to `SomeClass` ;)

Comment: I'm puzzled that no one else has pointed out that `public class SomeClass(string connectionString, string someOtherRequiredConfiguration)` is not valid C# syntax and that your two code examples are therefore very confused and confusing.

Comment: @DavidArno correct, I should've added the parameters to a constructor, it was written up too quickly. Not sure its confusing though, everyone here is fairly intelligent.

Comment: @James, except me, it seems ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both is not really great.

The first version is slightly better, because it at least *attempts* to be able to inject something.

The problem is, strings cannot be injected based on the name of the parameter (at least none of the standard frameworks does this and although theoretically possible, nobody in their right mind would try that).

You need a *type* to properly inject something.

```
public interface ISomeClassOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; }

    public string SomeOtherRequiredConfiguration { get; }
}

public class SomeClass(ISomeClassOptions options)
{
   //Do stuff
}
```

This class can now be used without much manual configuration with a dependency injection container. You only need to find a way to fill your options from somewhere.

However, the use of a connection string *and* other configuration leads me to a guess that only you can verify: The connection string should not be an option. Instead the `SomeClass` should probably get a `IDbConnection` or `DbContext` or other class injected that handles the nitty gritty details of what the database is. Because it might be a `SqlConnection` for production or maybe just an in memory database connection for testing. That is up to the container to decide and should not be inside your `SomeClass` logic.

If you are using .NET Core, have a look at the new [Options pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

Comment: While I get your point, I'm not quite sure you should be equating dependency injection and method parameters. Method parameters may be a "dependency" of the method (in the sense that the outcome can be different based on the parameter value), but that's not really an _injected_ dependency. Dependency injection focuses on how _classes_ are stitched together, not which particular values are sent to a given object. If anything, dependency injection seeks to ensure that the outcome of a method **doesn't** change when you pass a different parameter value, i.e. it works the same for any `IFoo`.

Comment: @Flater, I disagree. "Dependency injection" is simply "tell, don't ask", ie the thing, whether that be a function, object or entire library is told what its dependencies are, rather than it calling at to some service to find them. So parameters to a function most definitely are an example of dependency injection.

Comment: @Flater: though you are literally correct, for the correctness of this answer it does not matter if the first approach can be called DI or not.

Comment: I think the Options Patterns is what is needed here. Some discussion points too.

Comment: The given reason is "strings are difficult to inject", but in the proposed solution, _you still need to do that_ - just to another class. Anything you would do to get those strings into your implementation of `ISomeClassOptions` - e.g. factory, hardcode it, config file -  you could just as well do for `SomeClass`. Regarding injection of strings, you're back in the very same situation, just with an extra class. I _do_ agree with using an own type, but the reasoning here doesn't make sense to me - maybe I'm just missing something?

Comment: @R.Schmitz Well, whatever configuration system you use (for example the one I linked as the default for the projects the user is targeting), could be able to find options from configuration sources on their own. It's a build-in automatism, instead of hand-rolling your own version.Sure, in the end somebody needs to read that info from somewhere, but I'd prefer it'd be an automated system that treats all configuration the same way.

Answer (score 4):

```
//pull config from config file, then pass in to class
public class SomeClass(string connectionString, string 
someOtherRequiredConfiguration)
{
   //Do stuff
}
```

The rest of your answer talks about DI, but this particular snippet isn't really DI-oriented. This is a normal run-of-the-mill parametrized constructor.

I do wonder about `someOtherRequiredConfiguration`. Based on the name, I'm going to assume you've oversimplified the example and that the real code contains meaningful parameters.

---

```
public class SomeClass()
{
    //Do work to pull from config file in constructor or in parameter
}
```

> the class is responsible for retrieving the configuration it cares about

Objectively correct, but that doesn't answer whether it's a good idea or not. I will elaborate on this point.

> I think the second way makes DI much easier

Quite the opposite. What you've done here is *removed* the option to configure your class the way you want to. This makes it *harder* to mock, not easier. You're forcing yourself to create a new (probably derived) class whenever to you want to test against a different external resource (= different connectionstring).

---

> You could have an `IConfigRepository` or something if you wanted to control that separately.

What you say isn't wrong, but I just want to reframe what you said: your proposed solution now *requires* you to create an `IConfigRepository` before you can properly test. It's not impossible to do so, but it creates more work to have testable code, which is the opposite of what DI tries to achieve (increasing testability)

---

> But pulling the config values and passing them in at the composition root feels wrong to me.

The fact that you refer to `SomeClass` as a **composition root** makes me suspect that you're thinking about DI/testability in an unusual way.

The value of a parameter (connectionstring) has little to do with dependency injection. Dependency injection focuses on stitching together custom classes in a way that you can easily separate them in the future (e.g. testing a single component, or swapping a particular component for another one).

---

> Should a class be responsible for its own configuration?

It highly depends on the configuration you're focusing on. Some things don't belong in a config file to begin with and can simply be set as a `const` value.

If you can guarantee that `SomeClass` will always use a particular config key, without fail, then you can retrieve the key from inside the class (constructor or otherwise).

If `SomeClass` needs to be able to toggle between several connectionstrings (e.g. an application that uses multiple databases at the same time), then it needs to be configurable. A constructor parameter is the better approach here.

Comment: With regards to composition root, I mean the `SomeClass` would be created at the apps composition root (using manual DI, not a container), so currently there code calling the config file before creating the concrete class, so it can be passed it. I think the Options Pattern mentioned above might be the best solution

Comment: @James: That's valid technical approach, but it's not really DI specifically. Just because DI often occurs via constructor parameters doesn't mean that all constructor parameters are being used for DI. This is a fairly normal configuration that is unconnected to DI itself (even though there are some similarities, I grant you).

Comment: Upvoted this answer too as it makes good points, but I think Options Pattern is the answer I need in this case.